# Can I get rid of the blank spaces on top and bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css

I have a white space on bottom of this page (Learndash lesson page):
https://academiademeditacion.com/lecciones/introduccion-y-postura-de-meditacion/

It does not happen with the other posts or pages in the website. I have tried the following CSS and nothing appears to work. I do not find the problem. I did solve the top blank space though.

```html
    .container {
        height: 100% !important;
        max-height: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100000px !important;
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        margin-top: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    #page-container {
        height: 100% !important;
        max-height: 100% !important;
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        margin-top: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

.ld-tabs {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Delco

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the tree of your DOM, you'll discover that one of the elements has `margin` set to `1em` by this rule:

```
.learndash-wrapper .ld-course-status.ld-course-status-not-enrolled {
    display: flex;
    background: #f0f3f6;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: So, I was able to solve the issue with the top blank space, but now I can't find the issue with the bottom blank space.

Do you know what class or id should I edit by CSS and what should I edit in it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: not sure what bottom blank space is, is it supposed to be the height of the window or something?

Comment: I mean, at the bottom of the page, there is a blank space. I do not know what it is or how to delete it.